# Django-rest validações de senhas em dois campos

Tags: django-rest-framework

Como recuperar valores dos elementos html em uma custom validação com Django-rest ?

Como seria no django-rest a similaridade com o código abaixo ?

```
def clean(self):
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

    if password1 and password1 != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")

return self.cleaned_data
```

Já tentei com o ( *validate_password1(self, data):*), mas não sei como recuperar o valor do password2.

Também já tentei com (*to_internal_value*), mas preciso do retorno como em **validate_CAMPO**. *Exemplo (Campo:msg de erro)*

Answer (score 2):

Para fazer qualquer outra validação que requer acesso a vários campos, adicione um método chamado `.validate()` para sua subclasse `Serializer`. Este método usa um único argumento, que é um dicionário de valores de campo. Deve levantar um `ValidationError`, se necessário, ou apenas devolver os valores validados. Por exemplo:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class EventSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    description = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    start = serializers.DateTimeField()
    finish = serializers.DateTimeField()

    def validate(self, data):
        """
        Check that the start is before the stop.
        """
        if data['start'] > data['finish']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("finish must occur after start")
        return data
```

[Tradução do trecho da documentação.](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation)